# How to find the source location of a dynamic token in JMeter?

Tags: authentication, dynamic, jmeter, token

I've been using Fiddler tool to capture the HTTP request-responses, then manually finding out the source location of a dynamic token (in a recorded page). I'd then use regular expression extractor on that source page to extract and store the value of that dynamic token in a variable, and use that variable in later pages.

Just wondering if there's an easier way for this. Is there any tool in JMeter that can help us find the source location of a dynamic token?

Thank you,
--Ishti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of may 2015, there's nothing available OOTB except to save request / responses to file with ViewResultsTree and search in resulting file, or search in each response in ViewResultsTree gui.

An option would be to write a BackendListenerClient implementation that writes data in jdbc or ElasticSearch instance and uses it to search through SQL or elastic search queries.

A contribution would be welcome.

It is possible that this is implemented in future releases.